# Why is batch-import creating nodes but not relationships?

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, graph-databases

I used batch importer for converting relational data into neo4j. I have used [batch-importer](http://maxdemarzi.com/2012/02/28/batch-importer-part-1/) for this purpose. However I can create only nodes. I can't create relationships.

I used this command in command prompt:

```
java -server -Xmx4G -jar batch-import-jar-with-dependencies.jar target/muta-buyuk nodes.csv relations.csv
```

and result is:

```
Importing 5 Nodes took 0 seconds
Total import time: 1 seconds
```

my nodes.csv structure is:

```
id  name
1   kubra
2   ali
3   yusuf
4   esra
5   aysegul
```

my relations.csv structure is:

```
start   end type
1       2   parent_of
2       3   parent_of
3       4   parent_of
3       5   parent_of
1       2   ancestor_of
2       3   ancestor_of
3       4   ancestor_of
3       5   ancestor_of
1       3   ancestor_of
1       4   ancestor_of
1       5   ancestor_of
2       4   ancestor_of
2       5   ancestor_of
```

Comment: are you sure using tab separated format for relations.csv?

Comment: yes, it is tab separated. I use postgresql and I use psql for creating  cvs file. I run this command for creating tab separated csv files: "\copy iden_nodes to 'C:/Users/nodes.csv'delimiter E'\t' csv header;"

Comment: maybe nodes.csv and relations.csv use different end-of-line encodings?

Comment: perhaps you can share a sample of your actual files on dropbox or so, so we can have a look.